# Breaking down sin wave to frequency domain causing weirdness in phase

Tags: fft, signal-analysis, phase

I have tried many many different things and I cannot figure out why my phase is messed up. Here is what I am trying to do. I create a simple signal with a known wavelength, phase, and amplitude like below...

```
time_vec = np.arange(1, 11, 1)
wavelength = 1/.2
phase = np.pi
amp = 10
created_equation = amp * np.sin((2 * np.pi / wavelength * time_vec) + phase)
```

I then do an FFT to get individual frequencies. I end up with 4 frequencies from the FFT but only 1 at 2 hz is of any significance, which is exactly as expected. From here I am trying to get the wavelength, phase, and amplitude of this dominent frequency, create a new equation from these, and do inverse FFT to get back to my original, known, signal. Everything works except the phase is acting strange. It is producing mirror images of the expected result. I am using arctan2(Im, Re) for phase but I have also tried arctan(Re / Im) and get the same result. Here is the plot at 0 phase, and 1hz known signal.

[image]

and another at 0 phase, and 2 hz....

[image]

I can try any combination of phase and frequency and it is always slightly off. I have tried to manually shift the phase and this will solve the issue for any frequency at the same phase, ex. phase=0 and freq=any. But as soon as I change the phase, it breaks again so this is not a valid solution. What is causing this? and how do I fix it?

Comment: Phase is arctan2(Im, Re)

Comment: Thanks but it is still off slightly. It is no longer a mirror image though. lol. I will update and post new pics.

Comment: It may have to do with your time vector starting from t=1 when the DFT assumes the first sample is at t=0, but that is tough to see from what you showed. Can you show the math for the result and reconstruction for one case?